# AEM 6.2 - Touch UI / Granite UI with only one input field didn´t work

Tags: aem, aem-6

If I´m building a dialog with only one input field the dialog will not show up in the author.

Here is my example code (headline_dialog.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
          xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
          sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
    <content
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <layout
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <text
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textarea"
                            fieldLabel="Überschrift Text"
                            name="./text"
                            fieldDescription="Bitte pflegen Sie hier den Textinhalt Ihrer Überschrift."/>
                </items>
            </column>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

This is what we will see in the author:

[image: The Dialog will not show up]

If I´m adding now a second input field to the dialog. The Dialog will show up in the author:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
          xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
          sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
    <content
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <layout
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <text
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textarea"
                            fieldLabel="Überschrift Text"
                            name="./text"
                            fieldDescription="Bitte pflegen Sie hier den Textinhalt Ihrer Überschrift."/>
                    <example
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                            fieldLabel="Dummy"
                            name="./example"
                            value="exampletext"
                            disabled="true"
                            fieldDescription="Dummy Text"/>
                </items>
            </column>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

Now we see the Dialog correctly:
[image: With two input field the dialog shows up correctly]

Is that a bug in the new touch-UI? Or did I make a mistake in the first dialog XML file?

Comment: Do you see the node structure correctly via crx/de for the first xml under your dialog?

Comment: Yes, I can see it in CRX under "/apps/...". The include looks exactly like all other dialogs.

Comment: Can you remove non-ASCII characters from your XML: `Überschrift Text`